# How to remove specific pattern in string?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have data in that string is like `f <- "./DAYA-1178/10TH FEB.xlsx"`. I would like to extract only `DAYA-1178`

what I have tried is

```
f1 <- gsub(".*./","", f)
```

But it is giving last result of my file `"10TH FEB.xlsx"`

Appreciate any lead.

Comment: Try `stringi::stri_extract(f,regex = "(?<=\\./).*(?=/)")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are dealing with files. You need the basename of the directory:

```
basename(dirname(f))
[1] "DAYA-1178"
```

or you could do:

```
sub(".*/","",dirname(f))
[1] "DAYA-1178"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit`, we can split the input on path separator `/` and retain the second element:

```
f <- "./DAYA-1178/10TH FEB.xlsx"
unlist(strsplit(f, "/"))[2]
[1] "DAYA-1178"
```

If you wish to use `sub`, here is one way:

```
sub("^.*/(.*?)/.*$", "\\1", f)
[1] "DAYA-1178"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 <- gsub("[.,xlsx]","",f)
```

u can try like these it will give

```
f1 <- /DAYA-1178/10TH FEB

f3 <- strsplit(f1,"/")[[1]][2]

DAYA-1178 --> answer
```